# Can I "fail" authentication within OAuth2 Security Chain using a database call after OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: spring-security

With my security config looking something like this (and working fine):

```
    ...
    .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
            .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService())
            .successHandler(successFunction())
            .failureHandler(failureFunction())
    .and()
    ...
```

how would I go about taking the result of a database call (to my own database) which might indicate that the user should in fact not be able to access?

I am hoping to be able to somehow hook into the Filterchain, do my calls and then "land" inside the success-/faulureFunction

Which Filter would be the appropriate one, where to add it in the chain and how to cause success/failure?

I tried reading up on it but maybe I can't find the right words to get the right results.